# Trying to compile a x86 C program on a x64 RedHat environment

Tags: c

I have a bunch of C programs that were being used on a 32 bits environment and now I need to compile them on a 64 bits environment.

Hello all,

I am a COBOL Developer.

On the company I work for, we are migrating our Linux OS from 32 bits to a 64 bits version.

We did almost everything except for our C programs.

On our makefile, basically we have "gcc -c" and I added -m64.

Some programs compiled just fine, but others don't.

When our cobol programs calls those c subroutines we are having a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error message.

When I compile the C programs on a 32bits env I do not have any warning messages, but I have warnings on a 64 bits env.

```
/* mgetdat.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int mfqend ()
{
    char *Jobname;
    char *Jobno;
    char str[200];
    Jobname = (char*)getenv("JOBNAME");
    if(Jobname == NULL)
        Jobname = "JobUnknown";
    Jobno = (char*)getenv("JOBNO");
    if(Jobno == NULL)
        Jobno = "JobnoUnknown";
    sprintf(str,"/tmp/%s.%s",Jobname,Jobno);
    unlink(str);

    return 0;
}
```

This s the following warning I am receiving:

```
/exp/prod/src>make mfqend
cc  -c -m64 mfqend.c 2>&1 | tee mfqend.err
mfqend.c: In function âmfqendâ:
mfqend.c:12:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  Jobname = (char*)getenv("JOBNAME");
            ^
mfqend.c:15:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  Jobno = (char*)getenv("JOBNO");
          ^
cp -f mfqend.o mfqend.o2
ar ru /public/prod/lib/libpubbatsub.a mfqend.o mfqend.err
rm -f mfqend.o mfqend.o2 mfqend.err
```

I am running out of ideas here as I do not know much C language.

If anyone has any idea about what can be done about it, I would really appreciate...

Comment: You can't just magically convert 32-bit code to 64-bit code with a compiler/linker option. First, you don't necessarily have to recompile at all; 64-bit OSes usually happily continue to run 32-bit apps. We've upgraded all of our workstations to Windows 10 Enterprise  64-bit and not recompiled a single 32-bit application without an issue. Second, if you do have an actual need to convert to 64-bit, you have to make quite a few code changes to accommodate the differences between them (such as the difference in the size of pointers).

Comment: Try `#include <stdlib.h>`. And remove these casts at all.

Comment: @EugeneSh. pretty amazing. Just using "#include <stdlib.h>" solved the issue. As we do not have plans to touch those c programs, your suggestion was amazing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThiagoGracioso if you're the least bit curious as to **why** that solves the problem,  consider the source of the root problem in the first place. Proper use of `getenv` [*requires* including `stdlib.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv). When you didn't do that the C compiler happily just assumed there was some function `int getenv()` that took an arbitrary number of arguments and returned `int`. Moving to x64, `int` is still 32bit, but pointers becomes 64bit. Therefore your call was throwing out half the pointer bits, then casting back to x64 pointer, then storing the result..

Comment: @ThiagoGracioso The root of the problem, therefore, was not following the requirements of utilizing `getenv` in the first place. The cast should never have been there, and was only added at some past-time to squelch the warning that was telling you the problem all along (`int` and `char*` are not the same). The cast fixed *nothing*, rather it just masked the issue. The root problem came long before your port to x64. That port demonstrated how casting to squelch obtuse warnings is the *last* thing you want to do. Rather, identify the reason for the warning and actually address *that*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Perhaps that should go into an answer I was lazy to write...

Comment: @EugeneSh. lolz. there have to be dozens of duplicates of this issue (I know I've answered several personally). When if I get some spare time I'll try and hunt one down. It's by no means a unique situation. Props for recognizing the `getenv` prototype was in `stdlib.h` on-sight, btw. I never use it, so it would have taken awhile for me to come to the same conclusion. I'm sure those seemingly pointless casts were a big hint =P

Comment: Thank you both. I definitely was wondering the reason behind it but did not want to disturb you guys more than I already did. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @WhozCraig The casts were definitely a hint. I don't use this function as well, and was wondering what it is actually returning, so went to the man page right away...

Comment: @KenWhite, if your C code is strictly conforming then you can go from 32-bit to 64-bit without even a magic compiler option.  Recompiling and relinking with a 64-bit toolchain will do it.  Of course, it is sad but true that most code is not strictly conforming, but how much work might be needed to convert such code is wholly a function of the code.